# Trying to use forkJoin with subscription

Tags: angular, subscribe, fork-join

I am trying to use forkJoin on subscription, for some reason it won't work at all, I can't console log my code, most likely .subscribe is not even reached, what am I missing here?

```
public SUB_getActSearch: Subscription;

this.SUB_getActSearch = this.searchService.getActSearch({ ...searchOBJ2, PageSize: this.pageSize, PageNumber: this.currentPage }).subscribe((res) => {
        this.Act_Data = [];
        let headerPagin = JSON.parse(res.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
        this.elementsLength = headerPagin.totalCount;
        this.currentPage = headerPagin.currentPage;
        this.pageSize = headerPagin.pageSize;
        res.body.map((param) => {
          this.Act_Data.push(param);
        });
        this.ActDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.Act_Data);
        // console.log('Your form data : ', this.ActDataSource);
      });

  public testingforkJoin(): void {
    forkJoin(
      this.SUB_getActSearch
    ).subscribe(val => console.log("xxxxx", val));
  }
```

I want to use forkJoin on this.SUB_getActSearch and console log something as soon as this.SUB_getActSearch is completed, just to test forkJoin operator

Comment: You should get compilation errors from this. forkJoin doesn't accept a subscription as input, it takes an array of Observables

Comment: Is there any other way to wait for subscriptions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want do something when `getActSearch` completes?

Comment: Subscriptions are what activates and listens to observables, so no you can't wait for subscriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your console where you run angular, you should get some errors there. `forkJoin` doesn't take subscriptions as input.

Since you only have one observable (`this.searchService.getActSearch(...)`), there is no need for `forkJoin`. Your understanding of observables and subscriptions seem to be a bit off, but I'll make some assumptions about what you want to accomplish and put some comments on the way.

```js
public getActSearch$: Observable<any>; // specify correct type instead of any if possible

ngOnInit() {
    // I'm not sure if this code is inside an ngOnInit since you didn't 
    // specify where the code is in your example, but I'll assume it is. 
    this.getActSearch$ = this.searchService
        .getActSearch({ 
            ...searchOBJ2, 
            PageSize: this.pageSize, 
            PageNumber: this.currentPage 
        }) 
        // You will need to use shareReplay if the observable only emits one value 
        // and you want to be able to subscribe to it multiple times
        .pipe(shareReplay()); 

        // This will fire off the getActSearch request (which I assume is a http call)
        // And the initialize the values with the result
        this.getActSearch$.subscribe(res => this.initValues(res));
}

// I separated the observer code from your example into its own method
// so that you can choose when to initialize your values
private initValues(res) {
    this.Act_Data = [];
    let headerPagin = JSON.parse(res.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
    this.elementsLength = headerPagin.totalCount;
    this.currentPage = headerPagin.currentPage;
    this.pageSize = headerPagin.pageSize;
    res.body.map((param) => {
        this.Act_Data.push(param);
    });
    this.ActDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.Act_Data);
    // console.log('Your form data : ', this.ActDataSource);
});

public testingSubscribingAgain(): void {
  // Because the observable is replayed through `shareReplay`, when you come here you will fire a new http request. 
  // It's unclear if that's your intention.
  this.getActSearch$
      .subscribe(val => {
          // Do you want to reinitialize the values here?
          this.initValues(val); 
          console.log("xxxxx", val));
  })
}
```